# Compute discrete laplacian operator from distance matrix

Tags: euclidean-geometry, matrix-calculus, laplacian

I have the $n$ by $n$ distance matrix for a set of $n$ (irregularly spaced) points. How can I compute the discrete Laplacian operator for these data?

For context, my distances are true geodesics across an irregular triangular 3d mesh surface.

Comment: [Here is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40520133) which outlines a method for calculating the various differential operators on an irregular mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should read the article (apart from checking out the wikipedia page): [Discrete Laplace Operators](http://ddg.math.uni-goettingen.de/pub/laplacian.pdf)

Since you are working with discrete geometric notions, you should not rely purely on combinatorial descriptions of Laplace operators on graphs. You should implement discrete Laplacians that incorporate geometric information, not just combinatorial. Since, from what I have witnessed, no notion of discrete Laplacian captures all desired properties of classical Laplacians, you need to decide which properties are important for you and which are not. 
For that purpose however, you may need to calculate some more relevant geometric information from the geometry and combinatorics of your triangulated surface (Delaunay triangulations, Voronoy partitions, cotangents of angles of triangles...).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do so from a discrete set of points, because there are many triangulations that come from the same point set, and the discrete laplacian operator depends on the triangulation as well as the point set.

To make that more concrete, by choosing which diagonals to draw, you can triangulate the unit cube in 3-space so that $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ both have valence 6 or both have valence 3. The discrete laplacians, in these two cases, are different.

Comment: I did not mention the triangulation matrix because I thought the distance matrix renders it redundant, but I have that as well (I needed it to compute the geodesics).

Comment: OK. So what part of the first two paragraphs of the wikipedia entry don't you understand? The sum over $w : d(w, v) = 1$ (where $d$ is the **graph distance**) means the sum of points in the 1-ring of $v$, which depends on ... well, on what $v$ is connected to in the graph. So connectivity is essential.

Comment: Which Wikipedia page? I had not considered the graph perspective and am unsure how to apply it. I meant geodesic distance in the geometric sense. My distances are in meters, not numbers of edges, and my edges can be of any length. For that matter, my geodesics do not only follow the edges of the mesh but also lie across it's faces.

Comment: The one for "Discrete Laplace Operator": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator

Comment: Ah, so I need not the graph Laplacian, but the mesh Laplacian (paragraphs 3-5) for a 2d surface embedded in 3d space.  It seems the family of solutions is called "discrete Laplace–Beltrami operators" for which there are several discretization algorithms. The irregularity of my mesh will limit my algorithmic options. This is more complicated than I thought, and I will read more into this topic. However, I would be grateful for any thoughts you have that might point me in good directions. Also, would this topic be more suitable for a CS or Physics StackExchange?